# terraform azurerm_data_factory_pipeline assing type to the variables

Tags: variables, terraform, azure-data-factory, pipeline, azure-rm

in terraform documentation i found the follow example:

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_pipeline" "test" {
  name                = .....
  resource_group_name = ...
  data_factory_id     = ...
  variables = {
  "bob" = "item1"
}
```

but I need to create a boolean variable, in the portal Azure I have the type field.
how can I set the variable like this:

```
"variables": {
  "END": {
    "type": "Boolean",
    "defaultValue": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should that variable go? In the `variables = {...}` of the `azurerm_data_factory_pipeline` resource?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your question, if you are asking how to create a variable of type boolean in Terraform, that is done like this:

```
variable "END" {
  type        = bool
  description = "End variable."

  default = false
}
```

You can reference that variable then in the resource definition:

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_pipeline" "test" {
  name                = .....
  resource_group_name = ...
  data_factory_id     = ...
  
  variables = {
    "END" = var.END
  }
}
```

Or alternatively you can set it without defining the Terraform variable like this:

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_pipeline" "test" {
  name                = .....
  resource_group_name = ...
  data_factory_id     = ...
  
  variables = {
    "END" = false
  }
}
```